# How to print DateTime object in yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ format?

Tags: c#

Could anybody help me to find a formatter to print DateTime object in the following way:

```
2012-09-30T16:53:46Z
```

What does "Z" postfix mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal `Z` is actually part of the *ISO 8601 datetime standard for UTC times*. When `Z` (Zulu) is tacked on the end of a time, it indicates that that time is UTC, so really the literal `Z` is part of the time.

**[MSDN: Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)**